# Saving multiple objects and `stringify_keys' error. Help needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

While I'm trying to save multiple objects, I'm getting the next error:

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for #<Array...>
```

Any ideas about how to deal with it? 
My inputs:

Controller:

```
def create
@course   = Course.find(params[:course_id])
@students = @course.users

@students.each do
 @grade  = @course.grades.build(params[:grade])
end

@grade.each { |a| a.save }
end
```

_form.html.erb:

```
 <%= form_for ([@course, @grade]) do |f| %>

....

<% @students.each do |a| %>
<tr>
<td><%= a.last_name %><%= a.first_name %>
<%= f.hidden_field :student_id, :value => a.id, :index => @grade.id %></td>
<td><%= f.text_field :grade_evaluation, :index => @grade.id %></td>
<td><%= f.text_field :comment, :index => @grade.id %></td>
</tr>
....
```

That gives me next params hash for grade:

```
  {....

 "grade"=>[
 {"student_id"=>"1",
 "grade_evaluation"=>"5",
 "comment"=>"you are an idiot" },

 {"student_id"=>"4",
 "grade_evaluation"=>"5",
 "comment"=>"you too"         }],
 "commit"=>"Create",
 "course_id"=>"3"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over grades, but not over incomming parameters here:

```
@students.each do
 @grade  = @course.grades.build(params[:grade])
end
```

(notice, that for each element you are passing whole array, not array element).

EVENTUALLY this should look like this (but this is not a nice sollution, but it will fix your problem).

```
params[:grade].each do |grade_params|
 grade  = @course.grades.build(grade_params)
end
```

Take a look at nested attributes, this is definitelly thing your looking for: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Your solution didn't work. Sounds like we are inventing a wheel right there. Thank you for the link. I think, I should go that way. But your solution are going to help me to refactor the other part of my code. Thank you.